# How to reuse arguments in an inner function?

Tags: r

I have a function `do_something` that receives four arguments and calls an inner function `get_options`:

```
do_something <- function(name, amount, manufacturer="abc", width=4){ 
    opts <- get_options(amount, manufacturer = manufacturer, width = width)
}

get_options <- function(amount, manufacturer="abc", width = 4) { 
    opts <- validate_options(manufacturer, width)
}
```

Sometimes I do `get_options(400)`, other times I want to override the arguments `get_options(400, manufacturer = "def")`, other times I call `do_something("A", 400)`, or `do_something("A", 400, width=10)`.

It seems like I'm being redundant by specifying the same default values for my arguments in both functions. Is there a better way to have them share these defaults?

Comment: I'm struggling to see a question here. Your example is not particularly illuminating

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the ellipsis (`...`) and only give defaults to the lowest level function:

```
do_something <- function(name, amount, ...){ 
    opts <- get_options(amount, ...)
}

get_options <- function(amount, manufacturer="abc", width = 4) { 
    opts <- validate_options(manufacturer, width)
}
```

You should still be able to run all of the below:

```
get_options(400)
get_options(400, manufacturer = "def")
do_something("A", 400)
do_something("A", 400, width=10)
```

and with the same results.