# In a function with default parameters, how to apply this function with specific arguments in R

Tags: r

I am trying to implement a function that can change those files with the same size but different format to the same,

```
try.read <- function(file.name, sep = ',', header = F { 
                   #body is here#}
```

I know the parameter `sep` and `header` are defaulted, if I do not specify them in my function call, I automatically get them, like `try.read('my.file')` is actually `try.read('my.file, sep = ',', header = F)`.

However, I want to make this call also,

```
try.read(diff.file, sep = '@', header = T)
```

what should I do to implement the function `try.read`

```
try.read <- function(file.name, sep = ',', header = F{ 
              read.table(file.name, sep = #something here#, header = #something here#}
```

What should I do in there?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809254/how-to-reuse-arguments-in-an-inner-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-use the names. `R` will know that you want the variables from the enclosing context.

```
try.read <- function(file.name, sep = ',', header = F) { 
              read.table(file.name, sep = sep, header = header}
```